# Bug Symfony Can use "yield from" only with arrays

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a website with Symfony 5. I have a problem that I can't solve.
I need to be able to create entities and for that I want to use a form generated by Symfony.

Symfony sends me this error:

Can use "yield from" only with arrays and Traversables
If I modify anything in my "Entities" entity then symfony sends me back:

My field I was waiting for

Great, that's exactly what I need, but the problem is that if I refresh the page the error comes back.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Entities;
use App\Entity\Events;
use App\Form\EntitiesType;
use App\Form\EventsType;
use App\Repository\CriteriasRepository;
use App\Repository\EntitiesRepository;
use App\Repository\EventsRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


Class AdminHome extends AbstractController {

    protected $event;
    protected $entity;
    protected $criteria;
    protected $twig;

    public function __construct(EventsRepository $event, EntitiesRepository $entity, CriteriasRepository $criteria, ObjectManager $em)
    {
        $this->event = $event;
        $this->entity = $entity;
        $this->criteria = $criteria;
        $this->em = $em;
    }


    public function index(){

        $event = $this->event->findOneBy(['current' => 1]);
        $criterias = $this->indexCriteria($event);
        $entities = $this->indexEntity($event);

        return new Response($this->render('admin/home.html',[ 'event' => $event, 'entities' => $entities, 'criterias' => $criterias ]));
    }


    public function indexEntity(Events  $event){

        return $event->getEntity();
    }
    
    public function indexCriteria(Events  $event){
        
        return  $event->getCriterias();
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin/event/create", name="admin.event.new")
     */
    public function newEvent(Request $request){
        $event = new Events();
        $form = $this->createForm(EventsType::class, $event);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $this->em->persist($event);
            $this->em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('adminHome');
        }
        return $this->render('admin/event/eventNew.html', ['event' => $event, 'form' => $form->createView()]);
    }
    
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/entity/create", name="admin.entity.new")
     */
    public function newEntity(Request $request){
        $entity = new Entities();
        $form = $this->createForm(EntitiesType::class, $entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $this->em->persist($entity);
            $this->em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('adminHome');
        }
        return $this->render('admin/entity/entityNew.html', ['entity' => $entity, 'form' => $form->createView()]);

    }

    // /**
    //  * @Route("/admin/entity/edit", name="admin.entity.edit")
    //  */
    // public function editEntity(Entities $entity, Request $request){
    //     $form = $this->createForm(EntityType::class, $entity);
    //     $form->handleRequest($request);

    //     if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
    //         $this->em->flush();
    //         return $this->redirectToRoute('adminHome');
    //     }
    //     return $this->render('admin/entityEdit.html', ['entity' => $entity, 'form' => $form->createView()]);
    // }
}
?>
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;


use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EntitiesRepository::class)
*/
class Entities
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $entityName;

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Rates::class, mappedBy="entity")
    */
   private $rates;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Events::class, mappedBy="entity")
    */
   private $event;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $descriptionFr;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
   private $descriptionEn;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Themes::class, inversedBy="entities")
    */
   private $theme;


   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->rates = new ArrayCollection();
       $this->event = new ArrayCollection();
       $this->theme = new ArrayCollection();
   }

   public function getId(): ?int
   {
       return $this->id;
   }

   public function getEntityName(): ?string
   {
       return $this->entityName;
   }

   public function setEntityName(string $entityName): self
   {
       $this->entityName = $entityName;

       return $this;
   }

   /**
    * @return Collection|Rates[]
    */
   public function getRates(): Collection
   {
       return $this->rates;
   }

   public function addRate(Rates $rate): self
   {
       if (!$this->rates->contains($rate)) {
           $this->rates[] = $rate;
           $rate->setEntity($this);
       }

       return $this;
   }

   public function removeRate(Rates $rate): self
   {
       if ($this->rates->removeElement($rate)) {
           // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
           if ($rate->getEntity() === $this) {
               $rate->setEntity(null);
           }
       }

       return $this;
   }

   /**
    * @return Collection|Events[]
    */
   public function getEvent(): Collection
   {
       return $this->event;
   }

   public function addEvent(Events $event): self
   {
       if (!$this->event->contains($event)) {
           $this->event[] = $event;
           $event->addEntity($this);
       }

       return $this;
   }

   public function removeEvent(Events $event): self
   {
       if ($this->event->removeElement($event)) {
           $event->removeEntity($this);
       }

       return $this;
   }

   public function getDescriptionFr(): ?string
   {
       return $this->descriptionFr;
   }

   public function setDescriptionFr(string $descriptionFr): self
   {
       $this->descriptionFr = $descriptionFr;

       return $this;
   }

   public function getDescriptionEn(): ?string
   {
       return $this->descriptionEn;
   }

   public function setDescriptionEn(?string $descriptionEn): self
   {
       $this->descriptionEn = $descriptionEn;

       return $this;
   }

   /**
    * @return Collection|Themes[]
    */
   public function getTheme(): Collection
   {
       return $this->theme;
   }

   public function addTheme(Themes $theme): self
   {
       if (!$this->theme->contains($theme)) {
           $this->theme[] = $theme;
       }

       return $this;
   }

   public function removeTheme(Themes $theme): self
   {
       $this->theme->removeElement($theme);

       return $this;
   }


}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Entities;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class EntitiesType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       $builder
           ->add('entityName')
           ->add('descriptionFr' )
           ->add('descriptionEn')
           ->add('event')
           ->add('theme')
       ;
   }

   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults([
           'data_class' => Entities::class,
       ]);
   }
}
```

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    <button class="btn">{{ button|default('Créer')}}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: I faced the same problem today, it seems the problem was in the cache. A simple `php bin/console cache:clear` worked for me !

Comment: Thanks, i can't try your solution i have just remove my entity and replace it by an other one.